# Windows Server Audit Failure from Client

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, windows, windows-8, eventviewer

Every several minutes I get an audit failure from one of my clients running Windows 8 on ports 56280 to 56294 in the event log of my server which provides DHCP/DNS/DC for that client. Do you have any idea what those ports are or how I can find out more about this?

```
EventID 4625
Task 12544
LogonType 3 
LogonProcessName NtLmSsp  
AuthenticationPackageName NTLM
```

Comment: whats the event id?

Comment: @tonyroth coming to my rescue again Tony, I edited the question - so an account is failing to logon, how do I find out which one?

Comment: to get a better indication whats the failure reason, hopefully not account unknown!

Comment: Account For Which Logon Failed: it's actually the account I'm using right now on the client, the failure reason: Unknown user name or bad password. And the logon process: NtLmSsp

Comment: on the workstation thats trying to connect do a netstat -ano find the pid then find that pid in the task list whats the task?

Comment: @tonyroth Well... it seems to have disappeared, when it comes back, I'll do that.